# How to select duplicate cells on the same row-conditionally

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a spreadsheet with a range of cells that contain data

Range is: `A1:AD951`

Is there anyway I can use a formula to select (and after delete) any duplicate cells (after first value) ONLY on the same row?

I've tried to highlight with:

```
=COUNTIF(($A1:$AD951,A1)>1) or =COUNTIF($A1:$AD951,A1)>1
```

Without success, excel warn me about an error in the formula (?)

Answer (score 0):

COUNTIF only works with single columns so your reference to `$A1:$AD951` isn't valid. Try

```
=COUNTIF($A1:$A951,A1)>1
```

to check for duplicates in row `A`